# Call to a member function setCurrentPage() on null in /var/www/html/myapp/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Export/ConvertToCsv.php:77

Tags: admin, grid, magento-2.1.3

I am getting the **error** as mentioned in my **question** **title**.

I have placed the following code in my **ui-component** based listing file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">zipcode_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Zipcode</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="zipcode_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">RB\CheckDelivery\Model\Zipcodes\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">zipcode_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>

        <exportButton name="export_button">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.zipcode_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </exportButton>

        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <filterSelect name="store_id">
                <argument name="optionsProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
                    <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store\Options</argument>
                </argument>
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">${ $.parentName }</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">store_id</item>
                        <item name="caption" xsi:type="string" translate="true">All Store Views</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store View</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterSelect>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="checkdelivery/zipcode/massDelete"/>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="status">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Change status</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <argument name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">enable</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="checkdelivery/zipcode/massStatus">
                            <param name="status">1</param>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">disable</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Disable</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="checkdelivery/zipcode/massStatus">
                            <param name="status">2</param>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="review_listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>

    <columns name="zipcode_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.zipcode_columns.actions</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">zipcode_id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="zipcode_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="zipcode">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Zipcode</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="city">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">City</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="region_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">RB\Operationalzones\Model\Source\Region</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">State/Province</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="country_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Country</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="RB\CheckDelivery\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\ZipcodeActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">zipcode_id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**DataProvider :**

```
<?php

namespace RB\CheckDelivery\Model\Zipcodes;

use RB\CheckDelivery\Model\ResourceModel\Zipcode\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;

/**
 * Class DataProvider
 */
class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block\Collection
     */
    protected $collection;

    /**
     * @var DataPersistorInterface
     */
    protected $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $loadedData;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $blockCollectionFactory
     * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $blockCollectionFactory,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $blockCollectionFactory->create();
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

     /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function addFilter(\Magento\Framework\Api\Filter $filter)
    {
        if (isset($this->addFilterStrategies[$filter->getField()])) {
            $this->addFilterStrategies[$filter->getField()]
                ->addFilter(
                    $this->getCollection(),
                    $filter->getField(),
                    [$filter->getConditionType() => $filter->getValue()]
                );
        } else {
            parent::addFilter($filter);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to know what else I need for export functionality to work.

Any help will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just figured out the problem.

I was using the wrong Dataprovider type.

Basically there are two kinds, you can refer below link:

[Magento 2: What's the Difference Between the Two Grid Component Data Providers?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125007/magento-2-whats-the-difference-between-the-two-grid-component-data-providers)

I made following changes in my code :

**zipcode_listing.xml** :

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">zipcode_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Zipcode</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="zipcode_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">zipcode_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">zipcode_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <component name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.zipcode_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </component>
        <exportButton name="export_button">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.zipcode_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </exportButton>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing_data_source</item>
                    <item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filterSearch>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.zipcode_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.zipcode_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="checkdelivery/zipcode/massDelete"/>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="status">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Change status</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <argument name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">enable</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="checkdelivery/zipcode/massStatus">
                            <param name="status">1</param>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">disable</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Disable</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="checkdelivery/zipcode/massStatus">
                            <param name="status">2</param>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.zipcode_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns  name="zipcode_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.zipcode_columns_editor</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root }</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
         <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">zipcode_id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="zipcode_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <!--<item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>-->
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="zipcode">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <!--<item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>-->
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Zipcode</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="city">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <!--<item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>-->
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">City</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="region_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">RB\Operationalzones\Model\Source\Region</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <!--<item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>-->
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">State/Province</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="country_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <!--<item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>-->
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Country</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="RB\CheckDelivery\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\ZipcodeActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">zipcode_id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**DataProvider** : 
No need to create external Dataprovider, you can use the core UI Component  DataProvider

i.e **Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider** as mentioned in zipcode_listing.

The last thing you need is to set register **zipcode_listing_data_source** in **di.xml** where you configure collection for your grid.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

   <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="zipcode_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">RB\CheckDelivery\Model\ResourceModel\Zipcode\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

   <type name="RB\CheckDelivery\Model\ResourceModel\Zipcode\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">rb_zipcodes</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">RB\CheckDelivery\Model\ResourceModel\Zipcode</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type> 
</config>
```

**RB\CheckDelivery\Model\ResourceModel\Zipcode\Grid\Collection** :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */


namespace RB\CheckDelivery\Model\ResourceModel\Zipcode\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult;

class Collection extends SearchResult {


    public function __construct(
        EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory, 
        LoggerInterface $logger, 
        FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy, 
        ManagerInterface $eventManager, 
        $mainTable, 
        $resourceModel
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $mainTable, $resourceModel);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this block of code in your columns arguments

```
<item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
      <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
</item>
```

Add here

```
<columns name="zipcode_columns">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <!--start add this code -->
    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
         <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
    </item>
    <!--end add this code -->
    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.zipcode_columns.actions</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
---------
--------
--------
```

**UPDATE**

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
            </item>
            <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.zipcode_columns.actions</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
        <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
```

Comment: Still getting the error...

Comment: Check my updated answer. add `storageConfig`.

Comment: Sorry, It's still not working ..