# UI Component Grid Export CSV doesn't work when using custom DataProvider?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, export, data-provider

I have ui_component which was using custom data provider. My problem is the Export functionality `<exportButton name="export_button"/>` is not working. It throws error:
**Call to a member function setCurrentPage() on null**

[image]

[image]

Do you have any idea on how to fix this without creating new data provider?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem.

"*Using the wrong Dataprovider type.*"

Basically there are two kinds, you can refer below link:

[Magento 2 Data Providers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125007/magento-2-whats-the-difference-between-the-two-grid-component-data-providers)

Please check the Listing.xml file and compare it  from below Example :

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">zipcode_columns</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Zipcode</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
<dataSource name="zipcode_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">zipcode_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">zipcode_id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
<container name="listing_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
    <component name="columns_controls">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.zipcode_columns</item>
                </item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </component>
    <exportButton name="export_button">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.zipcode_columns.ids</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </exportButton>
    <filterSearch name="fulltext">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing_data_source</item>
                <item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </filterSearch>
    <filters name="listing_filters">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.zipcode_columns</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                    <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.zipcode_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </filters>
    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <action name="delete">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete selected items?</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="checkdelivery/zipcode/massDelete"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
        <action name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Change status</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">enable</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="checkdelivery/zipcode/massStatus">
                        <param name="status">1</param>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">disable</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Disable</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="checkdelivery/zipcode/massStatus">
                        <param name="status">2</param>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </massaction>
    <paging name="listing_paging">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                </item>
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.zipcode_columns.ids</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </paging>
</container>
<columns  name="zipcode_columns">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
            </item>
            <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.zipcode_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zipcode_listing.zipcode_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root }</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">zipcode_id</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </selectionsColumn>
    <column name="zipcode_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <!--<item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>-->
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="zipcode">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <!--<item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>-->
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Zipcode</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <column name="city">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <!--<item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>-->
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">City</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
```

**DataProvider :** No need to create external Dataprovider, you can use the core UI Component DataProvider

**i.e** Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider as mentioned in zipcode_listing.

The last thing you need is to set register **zipcode_listing_data_source in di.xml** where you configure collection for your grid.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

   <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="zipcode_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">RB\CheckDelivery\Model\ResourceModel\Zipcode\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

   <type name="RB\CheckDelivery\Model\ResourceModel\Zipcode\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">rb_zipcodes</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">RB\CheckDelivery\Model\ResourceModel\Zipcode</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>  </config>
```

> **RB\CheckDelivery\Model\ResourceModel\Zipcode\Grid\Collection :**

```
<?php

namespace RB\CheckDelivery\Model\ResourceModel\Zipcode\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult;

class Collection extends SearchResult {


    public function __construct(
        EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory, 
        LoggerInterface $logger, 
        FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy, 
        ManagerInterface $eventManager, 
        $mainTable, 
        $resourceModel
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $mainTable, $resourceModel);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this one helps me